# Javascript - Replace function error for non-rounded numbers

Tags: javascript

Used below Javascript code to replace the comma to calculate the rates. With comma & exact decimal it works fine.

**Example:** if data-rate="3,300.99" or "24.20" or "35.00".. no issues. it works fine as expected.

But, when value of **Ex:** data-rate="22.68". Getting below error. Cant use math.round as we need to get exact value as output.

> $("#ele").data(...).replace is not a function

```js
var addOnRate = $("#ele").data("rate").replace(/,/g, "");

console.log("addOnRate", addOnRate);
```

```html
<div id="ele" data-rate="3,330.99" data-tax="89.98">..</div>

<div id="ele" data-rate="35.00" data-tax="10.00">..</div>

<div id="ele" data-rate="22.68" data-tax="9.90">..</div>
```

Comment: div with duplicate `id`?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny its not duplicated.. just shown as example. we are using only one unique iD for this logic. when data rate = 22.68 or 34.33 (example).. giving error. Is there any other way can replace query string can change or do if condition to check whether , there in data attribute or not?

Comment: actually the problem is the last one is `Number` and first 2 is type of `String`, and the string has a replace method. that's why for last one it is not working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem there is that `.data()` converts data to the number, you can use `.toString()` to convert it and use as the string

```js
for(const el of ["#ele0", "#ele1", "#ele2"]) {
  var addOnRate = $(el).data("rate").toString().replace(/,/g, "");

  console.log("addOnRate", addOnRate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ele0" data-rate="3,330.99" data-tax="89.98">..</div>

<div id="ele1" data-rate="35.00" data-tax="10.00">..</div>


<div id="ele2" data-rate="22.68" data-tax="9.90">..</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `data` function is being clever and converting `"22.68"` to a number for you. But it doesn't recognise `"3,300.99"` as a number (because of the comma I guess) so that is left as a string. Strings have a `replace` method, but numbers do not. It's probably easiest to be consistent and get all your values as strings. jQuery's docs say to use `.attr("data-rate")` for that; or use vanilla JS `document.getElementById("ele").dataset.rate`.

Comment: Second `.attr("data-rate")`. It converted mine to string without issue. Very quick and easy solution to go with the current code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with plain Javascript pretty easily:

```js
let addOnRates = [...document.querySelectorAll(".ele")].map(el => {
    return el.dataset.rate.replace(/,/g, "")
});

console.log("addOnRate", addOnRates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ele" data-rate="3,330.99" data-tax="89.98">..</div>

<div class="ele" data-rate="35.00" data-tax="10.00">..</div>


<div class="ele" data-rate="22.68" data-tax="9.90">..</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is the `22.68` is cast as `Number` in this case by `data()` that's why it is showing you the error whereas 3,300.99" or "24.20" or "35.00". are treated as `String` and string has `replace()` method. So if you cast all of them to String then it should work for you.

```js
var addOnRate1 = String($("#ele1").data("rate")).replace(/,/g, "");
var addOnRate2 = String($("#ele2").data("rate")).replace(/,/g, "");
var addOnRate3 = String($("#ele3").data("rate")).replace(/,/g, "");

console.log("addOnRate1", addOnRate1);
console.log("addOnRate2", addOnRate2);
console.log("addOnRate3", addOnRate3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ele1" data-rate="3,330.99" data-tax="89.98">..</div>

<div id="ele2" data-rate="22.68" data-tax="9.90">..</div>

<div id="ele3" data-rate="35.00" data-tax="10.00">..</div>
```